# Programmatically detecting annotations on a Crocodoc PDF file

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, crocodoc

We're in the process of transforming from Box's Crocodoc platform to their new viewer. We want to detect which .PDF files we currently have that were modified using Crocodoc's Drawings (basically a vector object) and differentiate them from the rest of the unmodified PDF files we have.

Does anyone have a way to do this pro grammatically? We tried reading the PDF metadata using iTextSharp and couldn't find out the difference between the original file and the Crocodoc with the vector objects file with a 100% certainty.

Here's a link to a Crocodoc generated file **with** vector objects drawn on it:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1LOB69EyOWQKFSP4vlj6DUEYK1DUYC8Fz

Here's a link to the same file but **without** vector objects that were drawn on it using Crocodoc: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1nBxYXSC56G7kbqxHmcudUryN0OyjiTx9

Comment: I would say *yes, iText can detect annotations* because that is true in general (if we're talking about annotations as defined in ISO 32000). However, you are assuming that everyone knows Crocodoc, but as long as you don't share a file, we don't know what Crocodoc annotations are about, especially since you mention PDF metadata. I don't understand why metadata would be related to annotations. That makes your question very confusing

Comment: @BrunoLowagie thanks for your feedback. I'll modify my question to make it clearer.